# Application in HTML5/JS on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, cross-platform

I'm working on a mobile application in HTML and JS, for Android and iOS, it works really good. But for Windows phone, I got some problems (First image is just to be sure to use the good templates)

[image]

Until here, I think it's okay and I don't get any problems, I just copy all my HTML, JS and Images in the project and I launch the emulator, and I got some problems there :

[image: Here is my Solution]

[image: Here is the facebook plugin to like my facebook page]

```
render.addITwitter("//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FTo-Night%2F1405825763018380%3Fref_type%3Dbookmark&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80&amp;appId=1434429670175105", "facebookIframe", "no", "0", "true", "horizontal"); 
render.addITwitter("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?text=I%20am%20using%20this%20application%20:%20To%20Night%20", "twitterIframe", "no", "0", "true", "horizontal");
```

[image: And Here is my Google Map to show some stuff]

And for this image, i'm calling a google map to show the map.

I don't really understand why it's not working. The Javascript is enabled in the xaml and when I go on Internet explorer on the emulator, it's works.

Someone got a idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: can you show some of the code? I can't see where are you navigating and what is that page supposed to be displaying

Comment: I just edit the code for the third image, for the second it's a big longer but i but some explications.

Comment: You can debug the http request with a tool like Fiddler, to be sure that the request to google maps are created correctly and behave as you expected.